# How to Prevent "svn diff" from Generating Unicode Output on Windows

Tags: svn, powershell, diff, patch

On my Windows box, I tried to create a Subversion patch by using the command `svn diff > my_patch.diff`.  The resulting file was encoded with UTF-16, rather than UTF-8 or ASCII, so when I tried to use `patch` (from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm)) to apply the patch, it didn't work.

I was able to convert the patch file to UTF8 by opening it in Notepad and saving as the desired format, and `patch` handled it fine after that.  But, is there a way to get `svn diff` to generate UTF8 on Windows?

---

**Update:** As my answer indicates, it turns out that the problem is really unrelated to Subversion, `diff`, or `patch`.  It was PowerShell that was oh-so-helpfully converting the output to Unicode.  I'm leaving the question as-is so that someone with a similar problem might stumble upon it.

Comment: In linux flavors, a `--diff-cmd` can be given, is that also the case for the windows command line variant?

Comment: `--diff-cmd` is supported.  What should I use as the argument?

Comment: Side note: Subversion doesn't like UTF-16 or UTF-32. It will always treat them as binary files and therefore `svn diff` doesn't even work on them (braindead but still no fix). So, there (currently) can't be a way that `svn di` Unicode in anything else than UTF-8.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue. Thank you! The most frustrating part was svn patch did not report any kind of error; just executed with no output and no change to the files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After much head-scratching and experimenting with different `diff` utilities, I figured this out:

I was running my `svn diff` in a PowerShell command window.  PowerShell's output redirection operators **convert the output to Unicode**.

If I run `svn diff > my_patch.diff` in a `cmd.exe` shell, then everything works fine.

To make this work in PowerShell, one must use a command like this:

```
svn diff | out-file -encoding ascii my_patch.diff
```

I'm sure there is somebody at Microsoft who thinks this behavior is really awesome.